# My function in asp.net doesnt output what i want

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

My output i get is Peak Timing = 7am to 9pm  Non-Peak Timing = 9pm to 7am for every single type of graphs that i get which i get. Like the Flat rate tariff, i dont get 24 hrs but Peak Timing = 7am to 9pm  Non-Peak Timing = 9pm to 7am. I dont understand why.

```
@{
web.....

open database.....

var timing="";
 foreach( var PriceSlot in OtherPlanDetail){
     var OtherPlanName=PriceSlot.PlanName;
if(OtherPlanName=="FlatRateTariff")
{

    timing="24 Hours";
}
else if(OtherPlanName=="TOU_Scheme_1")
{
    timing="Peak Timing = 7am to 9pm  Non-Peak Timing = 9pm to 7am";
}
    else if(OtherPlanName=="TOU_Scheme_2")
{
    timing="Peak Timing = 7am to 9pm  Non-Peak Timing = 9pm to 7am";
}

    else if(OtherPlanName=="TOU_Scheme_3")
{
    timing="Peak Timing = 7am to 9pm  Non-Peak Timing = 9pm to 7am";
}
    else if(OtherPlanName=="TOU_Scheme_4")
{
    timing="Peak Timing = 7am to 9pm  Non-Peak Timing = 9pm to 7am";
}
    else
{
    timing="invalid";
}
}
<form>
<div id="accordion">
            @{
                foreach( var PriceSlot in OtherPlanDetail){

                var     CostOtherPlan=Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal((db.QueryValue(PlanCostQueryString,WebSecurity.CurrentUserId,PriceSlot.Slot1,PriceSlot.Slot2,PriceSlot.Slot3,PriceSlot.Slot4,PriceSlot.Slot5,PriceSlot.Slot6))),2);
                var OtherPlanName=PriceSlot.PlanName;

                <text>
                <h3><a href="#">Cost S$@CostOtherPlan with Plan : @OtherPlanName  </a></h3>
                <div>
                        <p>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
                                    google.setOnLoadCallback(Draw);
                                    function Draw() {
                                        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                                        data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
                                        data.addColumn('number', 'SGD');
                                        data.addRows([
                                        ['0AM', @PriceSlot.Slot1],
                                        ['1AM', @PriceSlot.Slot2],
                                        ['2AM', @PriceSlot.Slot3],
                                        ['3AM', @PriceSlot.Slot4],
                                        ['4AM',  @PriceSlot.Slot5],
                                        ['5AM', @PriceSlot.Slot6], 
                                         ['6AM', @PriceSlot.Slot7],
                                        ['7AM', @PriceSlot.Slot8],
                                        ['8AM', @PriceSlot.Slot9],
                                        ['9AM', @PriceSlot.Slot10],
                                        ['10AM',  @PriceSlot.Slot11],
                                        ['11AM', @PriceSlot.Slot12], 
                                        ['12AM', @PriceSlot.Slot13],
                                        ['1PM', @PriceSlot.Slot14],
                                        ['2PM', @PriceSlot.Slot15],
                                        ['3PM', @PriceSlot.Slot16],
                                        ['4PM',  @PriceSlot.Slot17],
                                        ['5PM', @PriceSlot.Slot18],
                                        ['6PM', @PriceSlot.Slot19],
                                        ['7PM', @PriceSlot.Slot20],
                                        ['8PM', @PriceSlot.Slot21],
                                        ['9PM',  @PriceSlot.Slot22],
                                        ['10PM', @PriceSlot.Slot23],
                                        ['11PM', @PriceSlot.Slot24]
                                        ]);
                                        var options = {
                                        width: 750, height: 240,
                                        title: '@PriceSlot.PlanName',
                                        hAxis: {slatedText:true, textPosition: 'none'}
                                        //hAxis: {title: 'TIME OF THE DAY', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
                                        };
                                        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('@PriceSlot.PlanId'));
                                        chart.draw(data, options);



                                    }
                                    </script>
                                    <div id="@PriceSlot.PlanId"style="width: 200; height: 240;"></div>
                          @timing;


                        </p>

                </div>
                </text>


                }
            }
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once place a break point at the entrance of if and check what you are getting into other plan name. If the value of the "OtherPlanName" differs with "FlatRateTarrif" then it will cause so. Once check the value you are getting into "OtherPlanName" variable.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. This should be a comment.